# Changing Qr Code tint color and background color in android

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am an Android Developer. I need to create Qr Code with tint color : green, and background color : black. However without going through two nested loops because it's taking lots of time to create depending on the device's CPU. Any other solution?

Comment: Are you using barcode API?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It is solved. Thank you